# Run two specific IT tests using SBT

Tags: sbt

Is there a way to run two separate test suites using `it:testOnly` with SBT?

I know that if I want to run one test suite I would use `sbt "it:testOnly directory.testName"`, and that if I wanted to run a set of tests that all match a certain expression I could for example do `sbt "it:testOnly directory.*"`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do two individual tests. I have tried

```
sbt "it:testOnly directory.test1 directory.test2"
```

and

```
sbt "it:testOnly directory.test1,directory.test2"
```

but neither of those work, and I can't find any documentation on it when I googled the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'd made a spelling mistake in the name of the second test. The correct format is

```
sbt "it:testOnly directory.test1 directory.test2"
```